403 Error When Making HTTP Request with Retrofit in Kotlin
I’m working on an Android project where I need to send an HTTP request to a search endpoint using the Retrofit library in Kotlin. The request works fine when I enter the URL directly into my browser, but when I try to send the request programmatically, I receive a 403 error.
Here’s the URL I’m trying to request: https://apkpure.com/search?q=free+fire
And this is the code snippet where I set up Retrofit and make the call:
interface ApiService {
  @GET("search?q=free+fire&t=")
  suspend fun searchResults(): Response<String>
}

val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("https://apkpure.com/")
    .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
    .build()
    .create(ApiService::class.java)


When I execute the request, I get the following error:
Response Error: 403, Error Body: <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en-US"><head><title>Just a moment...</title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;

It seems like the server is rejecting my programmatic request but not when I use a web browser. Could this be related to user-agent verification or some other form of request validation that the server is performing?
How can I modify my request to avoid this error and successfully retrieve the data as my browser does?
I tried to add a user agent t my request so this may fix the problem, but it did not, here is the code :
val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
      .addInterceptor { chain ->
        val originalRequest = chain.request()
        val requestWithUserAgent = originalRequest.newBuilder()
          .header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3")
          .build()
        chain.proceed(requestWithUserAgent)
      }
      .build()

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
      .baseUrl("https://apkpure.com/")
      .client(okHttpClient)
      .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
      .build()
      .create(ApiService::class.java)

Still gives the same error...

After some investigation, I’ve discovered that the website in question relies on JavaScript to process requests. This posed a challenge when using Retrofit for network operations, as Retrofit does not support JavaScript execution. Consequently, the requests sent via Retrofit are treated as if JavaScript is disabled, rendering it incapable of processing web pages that require JavaScript.
To address this, I experimented with the Scrape{it} library, which successfully handled JavaScript but introduced significant latency. An alternative solution is to utilize a WebView, which allows for JavaScript execution within its environment. By enabling JavaScript in WebView, you can manually extract the results from the page.
Here’s a snippet to enable JavaScript in WebView:
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();

webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

This approach should provide a more interactive experience, similar to that of a standard browser, allowing for the proper rendering of JavaScript-dependent content.

I have tested it with Postman and it works a couple of times returning the html body of the page but after 10 tries, it will return 403 Forbidden.
You probably called it too many times in a short time period and it blocked your request afterwards

It’s not an issue of sending too many requests; I’ve verified that. Interestingly, when I use the Postman web version, the request succeeds without any problems. However, the same request through the Retrofit library results in an error. This leads me to suspect that Postman might be including certain headers or performing some background operations that enable it to receive a proper response. Is there a way to replicate this behavior in Retrofit to achieve the same successful response?

You are making your requests to the website which is probably protected by a firewall (WAP) , their public website is made for normal users, I think that if you want to use the website for development purposes you need to make your requests to their API not to the normal website (if they have an api)
If they have a public api the address should be something like this: api.apkpure.com/search where api.apkpure.com/ is the base url for the api and search is the endpoint.
